# how get and print the last indexes of a value for a table query in Lua Script

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
JobList_Table = {}

function CheckList() --> Called whenever someone makes a purchase.
table.insert(JobList_Table,1,
     {
       ["BuyerName"] = "Marie", -->Simulating with the name Marie - In the original script this name is added by a function.
       ["LatestPurchases"] = "Potatoes", -->Simulating with Potato 
       ["DateTime"] = os.time()
     }
)

--[[ ->for simulate in print,keep the JobList_Table,1,because that's how the program inserts

table.insert(JobList_Table,1,
     {
       ["BuyerName"] = "Marie",
       ["LatestPurchases"] = "Strawberries",
       ["DateTime"] = os.time()
     }
)     
table.insert(JobList_Table,1,
     {
       ["BuyerName"] = "Emma", 
       ["LatestPurchases"] = "Chayote",
       ["DateTime"] = os.time()
     }     
)--]]
end

function ShowList() -->Executed for verification.

local NewUser = 1
local ExecutionName = "Marie"

if NewUser ~= 0 then

for Index,Data in ipairs(JobList_Table) do

if Data.BuyerName ~= nil and Data.BuyerName == ExecutionName then  
print(Data.BuyerName, Data.LatestPurchases, Data.DateTime) --LOGS SHOW
return

end
end
    
print("Dont Find Or Nil")
return

end
print("Is Not New User")

end
```

What this script does:

Whenever someone makes a purchase the script adds the "BuyerName","LatestPurchases","DateTime" .
And you can see the last purchase by running the ShowList() function

---

What I need :
Currently I can only load the log of the last purchase of each BuyerName, I want to be able to see up to 5 logs of the last purchases, that is, if the person bought 1 time, 1 log appears, if he bought 10 times, the last 5 purchases appear

for example in SQLServer/Query I would do like this:
SELECT TOP 5 BuyerName,LatestPurchases,DateTime from JobList_Table where BuyerName = "Marie" ORDER BY IndexID DESC

I know the logic of the "ShowList()" function probably needs to be redone, but I don't know how, I've been studying lua tables, but I'm literally stuck on this.
Could someone help me with examples please? thanks

Comment: If you want to see more, don't return after you find the first one?
Notice that `table.insert()` at the first index is slow since you have to shift all jobs.
`for i = #JobList_Table, 1, -1 do local job = JobList_Table[i] end` to reverse traverse the jobs, you need this if you add at the end. If you do not know the order, traverse the entire list, put found jobs in a temporary array, sort that array and print the first 5 results. Also you do not need to nil-check a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Since new purchases are always added to the top of your table, you can easily get the latest `x` amount of purchases by `y` like this:

```lua
purchases = {}

-- 9 purchases, 6 by "Marie"
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Marie", LatestPurchases = "Potatoes", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Marie", LatestPurchases = "Copper Coin", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Henry", LatestPurchases = "Flowers", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Marie", LatestPurchases = "Galvanized Nails", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Marie", LatestPurchases = "Alligator Clips", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Arnold", LatestPurchases = "Birthday Card", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Marie", LatestPurchases = "Voltmeter", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Winston", LatestPurchases = "Bananas", DateTime = os.time()})
table.insert(purchases, 1, {BuyerName = "Marie", LatestPurchases = "Bottled Water", DateTime = os.time()})

-- Function to get up to x latest purchases by name
function getLatestPurchasesByName(name, limit)
    local latestItemCount = 0
    local itemList = {}

    for _, v in pairs(purchases) do
        if v.BuyerName == name then
            table.insert(itemList, v)
            latestItemCount = latestItemCount + 1
            if latestItemCount >= limit then
                return itemList
            end
        end
    end
    return itemList
end

-- Requesting latest 5 purchases from Marie, then printing the table
result = getLatestPurchasesByName("Marie", 5)
for _, v in pairs(result) do
    print(v.BuyerName, v.LatestPurchases)
end
```